# override method by calling super

Tags: ruby

I have two files `a.rb` and `b.rb`.

`a.rb` has:

```
class Work

def create type, id, clean = false, implant = false, sizes
  if clean
    # Do this.
  end   
  if implant
    # Do that.  
  end
end
```

`b.rb` has:

```
class BlogWork<Work

def run
  @blog[:save] = create 'test', @blog[:id], true, true, img_sizes
end
```

Is there a way to call `super` on `b.rb` so that I don't need to reference `implant=false` and `sizes` on the main `a.rb` `create` function but still pass the `implant` and `img_sizes` values?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here. Do you just not like having to declare so many arguments for `#create`, especially as some are optional? Please be a bit clearer. Consider even putting down some psudeo-code for what you would hope to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to keep the create more generic, I may want to pass additional arguments from other ruby files, so I am trying to figure out how to override the create method.  Some files will want to call create by passing their own arguments that may differ from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class BlogWork

```
def create type, id, clean = false, implant = true, sizes
    super(type, id, clean)

    if implant
      # Do that.  
    end
end
```

IN a.rb

```
def create(type, id, sizes)
   if options[:clean]
     # Do this.
   end   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `create` method generic in regards to arguments, you can add an optional hash parameter at the end:

```
def create(type, id, sizes, options = {})
  if options[:clean]
    # Do this.
  end   
  if options[:implant]
    # Do that.  
  end
end

def run
  @blog[:save] = create 'test', @blog[:id], img_sizes , clean: true, implant: true
end
```

if you are using ruby 2.0 and up, and the list of parameters needed is known in advance, you can use named parameters:

```
def create type, id, sizes, clean: false, implant: false
  if clean
    # Do this.
  end   
  if implant
    # Do that.  
  end
end

def run
  @blog[:save] = create 'test', @blog[:id], img_sizes , clean: true, implant: true
end
```

Comment: I don't really want to add anything to create though.  Can't I override it with super from somewhere else and pass whatever I want?

Comment: what do you mean by `super`? `super` means calling the method in the parent class, but there are no classes in your code!

Comment: sorry, I added the original post.